# Running batch jobs in Pivotal Cloud foundary

Tags: spring-batch, cloud-foundry

We have a requirement to migrate mainframe batch jobs to PCF cloud but as 3R's of security Rotate, Repave and Repair it might be possible that in the instance where batch job is running as spring batch that instance can be repaved/repair and our running jobs got terminated. In that scenario how to ensure that during repavement/repair of an PCF instance our jobs will not get impacted. We are looking for best way to migrate jobs in PCF cloud, any help/suggestion will be really helpful.

Comment: Not sure there's a lot to say, but you have to plan for this possibility. When your application is going to be stopped for any reason, it's given a graceful shutdown. That means it gets a SIGTERM, followed by 10s to clean up and exit. If it doesn't exit, it's abruptly stopped with a SIGKILL. You need to write your Batch job to be aware of the signals and when it gets a SIGTERM to pause what it's doing and mark it's position somewhere. That way when the process restarts in a min, it can pick up where it left off.

Comment: Spring Batch has some capabilities that can help. It processes data in chunks and automatically records the position, so if you get a SIGTERM it should just be a matter of finishing the current chunk or aborting that chunk and rolling back anything it did. You might also consider looking at Spring Cloud Task or Spring Cloud DataFlow which provide some higher-level building blocks to run your batch tasks in environments like CF or K8s.